# translating street names with meaning creates a wrong address

Tags: google-maps, google-translate

I'm using google translate API to translate text in my application but when it comes to street names its not the right way t go.
I want to keep the phonetics of the name using the letters of the new language for example '1828 oak street' should be 'Calle 1828 oak' and not 'Calle 1828 roble' when translating to spanish, I can give a Russian example but then the problem would be lost in translation :-)

every name that has a meaning like Church Street, Main Street, Walnut Street, Maple Avenue, just naming few, will be translated to its right meaning and the result is the wrong street name.

any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Don't translate the street name at all, i.e. the right answer is '1828 oak street'. Else how will you deal with oak street, oak way, oak road, oak passage, oak avenue, oak boulevard, oak path, oak crescent, oak terrace, oak drive, oak lane, oak close and oak row all having unique translations in every language in a manner where it's obvious to the reader which translates to what? Note in the UK you often get such a cluster of road names close to each other. Alternative option: show both the fully translated and untranslated words.

Comment: There is likely no way to do this. I just tested wheter the Google Geocoding API can do anything in this regard using the `language` parameter, but all it does is translate the name of the country the address is in. For the reasons @abligh mentions above, I assume.

Comment: @abligh I would leave it but think about app that is origin is Russia, the language is Russian and leaving the street name as is when the app translates to english is not readable => the user has 0 chance of reading the street name, might as well leave it blank.

* have the same problem with translating a person name.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options I can think of:

1. Make a dictionary/matrix of words and how they translate across different languages. When given a string of an address in a known language, take the street keywords from a list for that language, and search through the string for matches. When this is received, replace the found keywords with their translations. **Pros**: more accurate. Won't use up query limits. **Cons**: will require a lot of manual work and cultural knowledge. (i.e. Languages like Russian have a ton of different words for streets, and may not match up exactly with English, as an example).
2. Translate the string into a default language (such as English), and check for keywords. Then, use Google Translate the keywords into the desired language, and substitute it into the original string. **Pros**: Simple and easy to implement. **Cons**: less control on the output or cultural differences.